Python interpreter if statement issue
So, I am making a really simple Python interpreter. But, there is a part in the interpreter that checks for if statements. But, whenever I use this interpreted if statement, it checks every other indented line (which is what code should be executed if the statement is true). My code is shown below.
def tof(c):
    if eval(c) == True:
        return True
    elif eval(c) == False:
        return False

def interpret(code):
    lines = code.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("//") or line.strip() == "" or line.startswith("   "):
            continue
        if line.startswith("write(") and line.endswith(")"):
            if line[6] == '"' and line[-2] == '"':
                print(line[7:-2])
            elif line[6:-1].isdigit():
                print(line[6:-1])
            else: # not done yet (variables)
                v = line[6:-1]
                exec(f"print({v})")
        if line.startswith("if ") and line.endswith(" then"):
            one = line.split("if ")[1]
            c = one.split(" then")[0]
            if tof(c) == True:
                for x in lines:
                    if x.startswith("    "):
                        interpret(x.split("    ")[1])
            elif tof(c) == False:
                continue
        if line[2] == "=" or line[1] == "=": # not done yet (variables)
            if line[2] == "=":
                a = line.split(" = ")[0]
                b = line.split(" = ")[1]
                exec(f"{a} = {b}")

code = '''
if 1 + 1 == 2 then
    write("This should execute once!")
if 1 + 3 == 4 then
    // asterisk are there to tell which message is which.
    write("This should execute once! **")
'''

interpret(code)

I tried breaking the loop as soon as it sees an unindented piece of code, but if I put something like this:
if True then
    write("Hello, World!")
write("Stops here :(")
    write("Never gets here..")

it doesn't get to the last line

for x in lines: is processing all the lines, not just the ones after the if line.

And when the loop continues, it starts with the next line after if, it doesn't skip all the indented lines.

So, should I add a keyword that ends the if statement? Like end or stop?

No, just look for the next line that isn't indented.

But you can't use for line in lines: as your main loop, because that doesn't allow the code inside the loop to change your position.

you can use iter() to convert the list to an iterator. Then you can use next() to get the next element of the list. This way, you can use it repeatedly inside the loop to update the position.

Will it still work with the .startswith() and .endswith() keywords if I convert to iter()?

What is your actual question? Are you asking why? I'd suggest you run the code in a debugger and step through it. For a how-to, try to find a video tutorial for your IDE.

Of course it will. When you do line = next(iterator) the line is the same string as when you do for line in lines:

interpret(x.split("    ")[1]) won't work if you have nested if statements. interpret() expects all the statements to be in its argument, but this will just call it with one line.

Aside: It's possible for both x == True and x == False to be false. In general, better to just use return bool(x) unless you have a particular reason to do otherwise.

I think it would be better if you change your approach.
make a function to interpret only one single statement and another to loop through lines this will help you avoid problems related to iteration.
Making an interpreter is not an easy task.

In this piece of code on line 24
for x in lines:
    if x.startswith("    "):
        interpret(x.split("    ")[1])

I noticed that you loop through the whole code from the first line just to interpret the if statement causing to reinterpreting the code again
and that's why your code is run twice instead of once.
to fix it enumerate through lines in the interpret function to keep track of the index.
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):

and then in the code of the if statement just interpret the next line and break when there is no indent like this.
for x in lines[i+1:]:
    if x.startswith("    "):
        interpret(x.split("    ")[1])
    else:
        break

and now it will output this
This should execute once!
This should execute once! **


This won't fix the problem with the main loop, which will continue with the next line rather than going to the end of the block.

Good point I didn't notice it.
You can just remove the enumerate thing and do lines = iter(lines) and like that it won't loop from the first line and no need to slice lines.
the problem is it won't interpret the next line right after the if statement block.
